# Selenium IDE - send keycodes to body element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I want to send keycodes to the `<body>` element of a web page using Selenium IDE.
For example keycode 96 that corresponds to the digit 0 on the numerical keypad.
Can I do this, and if so how?

I have experimented with a number of things but no success in sending keycodes. This is my closest shot:

> ```
> <tr>
>     <td>sendKeys</td>
>     <td>//body</td>
>     <td>0</td>      // <- here I would like to state "keycode 96" instead of "0"
> </tr>
> ```

I am using Selenium IDE 2.4.0 in Firefox 24.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here [using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2](http://blog.reallysimplethoughts.com/2013/09/25/using-special-keys-in-selenium-ide-part-2/).

I had to do some testing to investigate if the listed variables corresponds to the keycodes I was after, and it turned out well. Confirmed OK for ${KEY_ENTER}, ${KEY_BACKSPACE}, ${KEY_DELETE}, ${KEY_NUMPAD0}-${KEY_NUMPAD9}.

Solution to the example in the question:

> ```
> <tr>
>     <td>sendKeys</td>
>     <td>//body</td>
>     <td>${KEY_NUMPAD0}</td>      // keycode 96
> </tr>
> ```